# What does the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ look like?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The definition for a Borel $\sigma$-algebra is hard for me to grasp. I understand that it can be thought of as the "smallest" $\sigma$-algebra of some set from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250603/borel-sigma-algebra-definition-question).

For concreteness, if we take the example of a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on [$(0,1]$](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/measure_theory.html), what does it look like? More generally, what does $\mathbf{B}(\mathbb{R})$ look like?

A picture or image would be appreciated.

Comment: No one knows how a Borel set looks like. The concept is abstract and it cannot be made concrete.

Comment: For real analysis targeted treatments of the [Borel hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy), see my answers to [Is there any good text introducing a part of Borel-hierarchy which is in need in measure theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/683897/13130) and [Constructing sigma algebras in countably many steps](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3075888/13130). For discussions involving modern descriptive set notions that might be helpful to you at this time, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3330190/13130) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1614718/13130).

Answer (score 1):

This is a *very* large set. In what follows, I'm basically going to quote a discussion that can be found in the Notes and References Section of Folland's real analysis book (Section 1.6)

Start with some subsets, $\mathcal{E}$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Then proceed inductively. Let $\mathcal{E}_1 = \mathcal{E} \cup \{E^c : E \in \mathcal{E}\}$. Keep going by taking compliements and "unioning" it with the original set. Do this "more than countably infinite times." The result is:

> $\sigma(\mathcal{E})  = \cup_{\alpha \in \Omega}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}$ where $\Omega$ is the set of countable ordinals

(Prop 1.23 in my edition of the source quoted above)

---

Just to add to my note, I think the reason we work with sigma algebra in the way you mention in your post is to avoid dealing with this "transfinite induction." The non-constructive definition is often easier (conceptually) to work with.

Comment: Thanks, the reference you cited is the most useful I have seen so far.